# when I run mongod --config "C:\Program files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongodb.config" it repeats endlessly

Tags: windows, mongodb, cmd, webstorm

`mongod --config "C:\Program files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongodb.config"`
I don't know what else to say... I am startled and frustrated because that's something I've never seen before. Usually when there's error you get some message that you can analize and make it right. But I hit Enter and the line I typed gets looped and it looks like if I would press `arrow-up` key and `Enter` subsequently, except I don't. After a while I have to stop this and press `ctrl + c` to kill the job. Have anyone seen this behaviour? I am on windows 7 64bit.

Mongod.exe is in `C:\Program files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\` and this folder is in my `PATH`.

That happened today first time when I run the command from webstorm built-in terminal. When I run it in `cmd` it gets executed normally **BUT** when i put the command in `.bat` file and try to execute it - same sh*t happens even in `cmd`. ? I wish I would never switched back to Windows.

Comment: Is your batch file called `mongod.bat` or `mongod.cmd`? If this is the case, it is calling itself

Comment: it is called mongod.bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch file is calling itself (remember that in windows the current active directory is implicitly included in the list of folders to search for executable files)

Rename the batch file to something different to `mongod.bat` or `mongod.cmd` or change the reference to the program to execute from `mongod` to `mongod.exe`. Any of this changes will avoid the batch file to call itself.

Comment: I'll check that today after work and report the result, but your answer seems reasonable and I think it shall work. If so, I'll mark answer as correct. Thanks anyway!